# CSS Prinitng - Page-break-before causes table header not to repeat (internet explorer 8)

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have encountered the issue described above in a report that I have created and requires printing from within an ASP.NET application.

I have created a simplified version so I could try and find the problem.

Please take a look. Preview the page in the browsers print preview, you will see that the code I have highlighted bold causes the table header to not repeat. Remove the page-break-before and the header should reappear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">

        @media print
        {

        thead { display: table-header-group; }
        tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
        tbody {display: table-row-group; }

        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div style='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 602px; border: 0px solid #000000; padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma'>

<table style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: verdana">
<thead>
<tr><th align="center">HEADER</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin in tellus ante, eu pharetra neque. Pellentesque a blandit odio. Donec porta sodales arcu vitae commodo. Praesent eu dolor justo. Cras facilisis, tellus sit amet laoreet blandit, libero nibh pharetra lacus, nec sagittis odio tortor quis leo. Quisque rhoncus nisi at urna tempor feugiat. Sed fermentum augue ultricies nunc facilisis vel dignissim ante dapibus. Mauris auctor, lorem sit amet vestibulum ultrices, erat neque fringilla lacus, at laoreet sem risus pulvinar enim. Proin laoreet pellentesque neque, et elementum magna volutpat vitae. Curabitur et nulla velit, ut tincidunt ante. Proin ac nulla sit amet odio rutrum viverra a in nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
<br /><br />
Pellentesque eu lacus non nisi ornare viverra. Quisque arcu nunc, pretium in feugiat et, tristique venenatis odio. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc arcu velit, suscipit sit amet porta vel, volutpat id ante. Mauris et nulla dui. Cras elementum posuere euismod. Donec ante dui, molestie non tempus quis, fermentum quis tellus. Proin viverra tellus quis lectus pharetra ut iaculis neque pharetra.
<br /><br />
Sed sed gravida tellus. Etiam pulvinar nibh quis est tempus dapibus eu quis eros. Etiam vel urna nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet libero nec neque adipiscing feugiat quis non odio. Fusce malesuada magna et orci egestas eget lacinia erat adipiscing. Proin vitae euismod elit. Cras ut sem nisl. Ut ornare dolor at erat dignissim eu cursus tortor ullamcorper.
<br /><br />
Suspendisse vel odio a elit sagittis porta et vitae justo. Nam quis sodales neque. Donec magna sem, faucibus et semper sit amet, adipiscing sit amet mi. Vestibulum non neque ligula, vitae luctus nulla. Mauris quis libero pulvinar justo iaculis lacinia. Donec gravida eleifend tortor. Maecenas tristique iaculis nunc, eu sagittis dolor interdum et. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
<br /><br />
Duis orci leo, dapibus vestibulum luctus nec, accumsan tempor dolor. Donec blandit venenatis erat, et volutpat quam hendrerit eu. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque risus nulla, malesuada sed semper ac, molestie nec est. In nec dignissim sem. Nulla enim nunc, eleifend eu fringilla sagittis, pellentesque non urna. Sed mi diam, ullamcorper et accumsan quis, placerat ut nisi. Nunc purus neque, semper non posuere ut, vestibulum vel odio.
<br /><br />
Maecenas aliquam sodales eros, sed faucibus mauris mattis eget. Nulla erat lectus, luctus id fermentum eu, posuere ac tellus. Praesent nisl erat, cursus eu tincidunt congue, viverra rhoncus enim. Pellentesque orci nisi, sagittis vel pretium posuere, pellentesque at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus felis odio, tincidunt in molestie id, aliquet id magna. Vestibulum sit amet orci eget felis tempus cursus. Nullam aliquet, lacus eget pharetra rhoncus, nisi orci pellentesque felis, id vestibulum mauris turpis aliquet risus. Sed rutrum est non est adipiscing ut dictum odio feugiat. Integer arcu nunc, porta pharetra facilisis ut, congue congue dolor. Quisque metus leo, cursus eget viverra iaculis, sodales eu leo. Vivamus ipsum lorem, fringilla sed sagittis vel, commodo quis lectus. Nunc ornare accumsan diam, ut aliquet purus laoreet sit amet. Pellentesque lacinia ligula quis ipsum dictum quis malesuada turpis semper.
<br /><br />
Duis laoreet auctor nibh a fermentum. Phasellus sapien risus, sodales et mollis in, dictum at nisi. Vestibulum eu nibh nec nulla pretium ornare. Aenean at ipsum orci, a laoreet nisl. In fermentum feugiat eros, sed gravida ipsum porta nec. Suspendisse luctus porta erat sit amet gravida. Nunc in lacus in odio accumsan euismod et a elit. Curabitur bibendum mauris bibendum dolor gravida dapibus. Quisque urna dolor, pulvinar tincidunt posuere dignissim, fringilla vel tortor. Morbi pellentesque sollicitudin eros ac tempus. Aliquam erat volutpat.
<br /><br />
Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam congue, mi aliquet eleifend consequat, metus eros posuere augue, sed accumsan nunc justo sit amet est. Duis sed felis vel elit scelerisque tristique sit amet quis diam. Fusce ut ultricies odio. Mauris scelerisque placerat tempor. Sed vestibulum mollis velit nec imperdiet. Sed elementum sodales metus, et fermentum leo aliquet auctor. Ut at nisl vitae purus rhoncus aliquam. Sed aliquet libero ac est egestas quis condimentum nisi rutrum. Donec condimentum vehicula odio, eu dignissim neque pulvinar a. Integer lobortis tempus blandit. Nullam faucibus lorem sed mauris consectetur id viverra turpis suscipit.
<br /><br />
Sed id diam neque. Donec elementum, enim sit amet ultrices semper, quam justo fringilla dolor, quis condimentum velit orci vel felis. Duis a elit vel nibh convallis dictum. Nam vel arcu nibh, id pretium orci. Maecenas vel dui nisi, id consequat nibh. Nulla blandit eleifend nunc varius semper. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut condimentum nibh. Pellentesque sit amet faucibus justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse potenti. Sed eget leo mauris. Vivamus luctus, felis at aliquet imperdiet, nibh erat auctor lacus, ac dignissim orci neque faucibus sapien. Suspendisse tempus venenatis purus ac facilisis. Aenean ac ultrices arcu.
<br /><br />
Suspendisse posuere, orci eget luctus tristique, odio lectus varius orci, eu mattis erat ante ac risus. Donec dictum pretium leo, eu porta enim dapibus eget. Donec in libero tortor, id tempus libero. Nunc magna tellus, placerat ut adipiscing vitae, volutpat ac arcu. Quisque sit amet leo massa. Nunc cursus, odio nec molestie sollicitudin, leo tellus dictum magna, eu sollicitudin libero ligula ac urna. Morbi ac sapien libero, ut eleifend massa. Etiam a risus vitae ipsum tempus pharetra sit amet vitae erat. Morbi sit amet lorem vulputate magna ultrices tincidunt sed vel urna. Aenean pulvinar, risus quis pharetra tincidunt, purus est accumsan odio, et accumsan turpis massa vitae leo. Vivamus at eros dolor. Donec ornare, nulla ut venenatis adipiscing, purus urna vestibulum nisi, placerat tincidunt nibh tortor vitae arcu. Vestibulum id turpis erat, ut adipiscing lorem. Duis venenatis, magna id lobortis accumsan, velit nisl convallis augue, sit amet interdum urna lorem sit amet sapien. Curabitur facilisis convallis lorem sit amet mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
<br /><br />
Quisque eget nunc leo. Vivamus rhoncus ultrices dolor in porta. Phasellus condimentum tempor justo nec facilisis. Sed consequat dictum dui, eget lacinia arcu rhoncus eget. Curabitur vehicula laoreet nunc quis tincidunt. Maecenas eget massa sed ligula interdum euismod quis vitae urna. Praesent luctus, dolor a faucibus tristique, purus lorem aliquam lectus, sed hendrerit ante nisl vel ligula.
<br /><br />

**<div style="page-break-before: always">**
Curabitur pulvinar sollicitudin est id elementum. Vestibulum quis lacus nisl. In pretium quam vel diam iaculis sit amet tristique justo viverra. Vestibulum ut magna nibh, quis pulvinar enim. Nulla facilisi. Sed posuere pulvinar urna, a porta odio congue in. Curabitur faucibus turpis quis nibh semper tincidunt. Ut egestas, justo ut vehicula elementum, magna eros sagittis nulla, placerat euismod nibh quam eget quam. Nullam placerat turpis vel lorem pharetra pharetra. Nunc eros nisl, aliquet rutrum sollicitudin et, ultrices volutpat augue. Maecenas dapibus adipiscing mattis. Nulla vitae velit tortor. Proin suscipit, augue in egestas aliquam, massa nisl pharetra mauris, sed vulputate lacus mi sit amet nibh. Donec ut justo tortor, non semper ligula. Nunc facilisis blandit lorem at pulvinar.
</div>
<br /><br />
Integer imperdiet faucibus mattis. Integer condimentum scelerisque erat, sed adipiscing dui condimentum vel. Etiam aliquet tempus neque, in fermentum massa tristique eu. Sed tempus neque vel eros tincidunt eget lobortis massa accumsan. Ut enim elit, rutrum vel adipiscing egestas, gravida nec urna. Proin fringilla aliquet hendrerit. Aenean a porttitor nunc. Ut vestibulum malesuada massa sit amet dictum. Duis ut sem ac augue fermentum tincidunt. Aliquam convallis pellentesque elementum. Suspendisse accumsan, lectus vitae tempus elementum, risus urna lacinia nunc, non dapibus sem nunc sit amet neque. Integer eu metus erat. Donec at ante neque. Nullam convallis odio sit amet enim sollicitudin vel vestibulum turpis aliquam.
<br /><br />
Aenean mattis velit vel ipsum eleifend sit amet auctor metus fringilla. Quisque a lacus orci. Ut luctus vulputate imperdiet. Mauris luctus massa at erat posuere sit amet convallis magna malesuada. Mauris tempus auctor suscipit. Phasellus eu est vel metus pharetra commodo ac posuere orci. Duis massa purus, lobortis et fringilla et, venenatis eget odio. Fusce vel sapien nisl. Suspendisse nisi nisi, tempor ut volutpat vitae, pharetra id ligula. Donec ipsum enim, dignissim et pharetra nec, vehicula et mauris. Ut sit amet nisl odio. Sed eleifend auctor metus, vel laoreet diam varius vel. Vestibulum sit amet augue nec massa faucibus rhoncus. Nulla sodales justo nec nisl commodo facilisis. Aenean euismod tortor eget lorem ultricies tincidunt.
<br /><br />
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque mi dolor, hendrerit a laoreet vehicula, elementum ut elit. Nullam sodales justo sed turpis volutpat blandit. Mauris augue est, tincidunt at vestibulum vitae, vestibulum non velit. Ut ac bibendum orci. Vestibulum lacus velit, rhoncus sed pellentesque ac, aliquam vitae sem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam condimentum nulla lacinia purus luctus et molestie eros cursus. Ut quis erat at magna aliquet laoreet. Suspendisse iaculis hendrerit vulputate.
<br /><br />
Etiam lobortis tortor lectus. Curabitur a ligula lorem. Donec vel odio a urna fermentum tincidunt in in libero. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi vel dui vitae ligula interdum ultricies in nec nisi. Sed sit amet odio in massa sodales mattis. Nunc non dolor ac turpis laoreet ultrices quis pellentesque felis. In egestas justo sed libero molestie in posuere odio condimentum. Morbi ultrices nibh vitae nisi posuere molestie. Fusce tempor porttitor leo, quis congue turpis congue non. Aliquam lorem libero, lacinia eget egestas nec, consectetur vitae eros. Cras interdum elementum odio, a venenatis odio gravida in. In vestibulum volutpat libero id vehicula. Nulla et vehicula eros. Mauris lacinia leo vitae lectus accumsan dignissim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br /><br />
Vestibulum sollicitudin sollicitudin consectetur. Vivamus fringilla gravida tempus. Phasellus vel fermentum erat. Maecenas auctor euismod lectus et vestibulum. Vivamus fringilla urna et justo rutrum imperdiet. Nunc a diam interdum nulla porta tempor. Nulla tellus risus, dignissim fringilla laoreet ac, lacinia et risus. Aliquam ut est orci, non molestie turpis. Etiam fringilla leo eget felis luctus et blandit nulla porta. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
<br /><br />
In sapien neque, varius at elementum vel, rutrum ut mauris. Phasellus pellentesque facilisis lacinia. Vivamus interdum nibh quis elit vehicula eget faucibus mauris commodo. Donec odio leo, faucibus in pellentesque a, pulvinar vel velit. Phasellus et sagittis felis. Phasellus ultrices elit sed mi tincidunt vel viverra nisl vestibulum. In eu augue nec odio ultrices tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris ut urna ligula. Pellentesque tempus, tellus blandit placerat faucibus, nulla lorem dignissim neque, ut iaculis tortor orci nec ligula. Nunc sodales convallis mattis. Etiam ac neque ac nisi volutpat imperdiet. Sed semper eleifend tellus, eget porta eros molestie ut. Quisque at ante sem. Donec non dolor tincidunt ipsum convallis suscipit. Aliquam ipsum nibh, dapibus at imperdiet tempus, fermentum ut velit.
<br /><br />
Vestibulum nibh orci, tincidunt nec sodales sit amet, lacinia vel nisi. Praesent tempor porttitor commodo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec suscipit, nunc in condimentum semper, tellus orci egestas nisl, pellentesque malesuada lacus lacus ac turpis. Donec at sapien ante. Praesent cursus dapibus turpis et porta. Etiam imperdiet aliquam augue, in varius sem tempor vitae. Phasellus at nunc id nisl vulputate porta vitae vitae quam.
<br /><br />
Morbi sodales nibh non lectus tincidunt elementum. Donec feugiat, nisi sit amet accumsan molestie, tellus lectus condimentum est, ut vulputate tellus ipsum in nisi. Duis mattis lorem et est vestibulum eu sollicitudin erat sodales. Integer porta varius imperdiet. Ut suscipit, lacus vel gravida iaculis, ipsum erat ultricies turpis, et egestas lacus sem id libero. Proin at mauris vel mi lobortis convallis vitae et tortor. In elementum mi vel ipsum tempus bibendum. Nam adipiscing, sem non semper rutrum, felis est lacinia felis, faucibus mollis diam ante et nisl. Nam erat eros, faucibus non porta vitae, rhoncus sit amet velit. Vestibulum sed elementum mauris. Praesent neque dolor, bibendum vel luctus lacinia, viverra nec odio. Morbi pharetra luctus ante non rutrum. Pellentesque rutrum, orci eu fringilla condimentum, felis massa tempor purus, quis rhoncus massa libero ac tortor. Phasellus a sapien est. Integer vulputate mauris eu erat pellentesque dictum. Phasellus eu lorem sed eros commodo convallis a at odio. </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this instead it solves your problem, however, it is strongly advised not to use page-breaking properties and table together by [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp)

code is here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rjs47/2/)

```
 <table style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: verdana; page-break-before: always">
 <thead>
 <tr><th align="center">HEADER</th></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<tr><td>
```

Basically, I created a second table where your desired page break should occur. And place the style of page-break-before: always on the table.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Basically, I need to close the encapsulating table, start a new one, and repeat the header information?

Comment: Yes, I updated the jsfiddle code again I left out the closing td and tr tags.